# no route matches POST / GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, http-post

How define routes for POST/PUT/GET methods when using 'form_tag' form? should I define in model a method POST or PUT? Or if I have e.g. browsing method then I should do with route something like this: (warning! pseudo-code below)

```
match 'browsing/mymethod' => 'browsing#post'
```

please help! :(

Comment: Please rephrase the question, it is unclear what you are asking.  Please post the code that has led to this issue and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your form does not alter the database state (does not create, update or delete records) nor does it contain sensitive data (like login credentials), for example if it's a search form and you use it to filter results, use the GET HTTP verb:

   `get 'browsing/mymethod' => 'browsing#filter'`
2. If it's a form that creates data in the database or it creates some resource (starts an authentication session for example), use the POST HTTP verb:

   `post 'browsing/mymethod' => 'browsing#create'`

   NOTE: We are talking about the action where the form submits, not the possible auxiliary action that displays the form!
3. If it's a form that updates data in the database or it changes some resource, use the PUT HTTP verb:

   `put 'browsing/mymethod' => 'browsing#update'`
4. Finally, if it's a form that when submitted, deletes data, (usually just a button, no other fields in the form), use DELETE HTTP verb:

   `delete 'browsing/mymethod' => 'browsing#destroy'`

Comment: but how bind that actions with form submit button?

Comment: `post 'browsing/mymethod' => 'browsing#create', :as => 'create_stuff'` and in view: `form_for create_stuff_path do ...`. Please read rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org